# Error "CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 123" linq vb.net

Tags: sql, .net, database, vb.net, linq

I have a database with the link "dtschool.dbml" and I want to create this database in SQL Server
When running this code

```
   Dim dt As New SchoolData.linqSchoolsDataContext
    Dim sd As New SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    sd.DataSource = "LAPTOP-AJM33RB1\TESTSERVER"
    sd.IntegratedSecurity = True
    dt.Connection.ConnectionString = sd.ConnectionString
    dt.Connection.Open()
    dt.CreateDatabase()
```

I see this error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.TESTSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\|DataDirectory|_Database_Schools_dtSchools.mdf.mdf'.
```

CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.'

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuYAY.png)

Comment: You wouldn't call `CreateDatabase` if you're distributing an MDF file with your app. In that case, you can deploy a file that already contains the desired schema so there's no need. You would only need to create a database if you're creating a new attached database, which you can't deploy as part of your application.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you , How can create database with dbml? i update my question

Comment: The path contains invalid characters `DATA\|DataDirectory|`

Comment: I don't use L2S but it's fairly obvious what's wrong with that file path so you need to determine where the incorrect part is coming from and change to what it should be. My guess would be that you have a connection string in the config file and you have simply moved the `"AttachDbFilename"` value to `"InitialCatalog"` when they mean different things. If you have `"InitialCatalog"` set to `"|DataDirectory|_Database_Schools_dtSchools.mdf"` in your connection string then that's the problem. A database name gas no folder path and no file extension. It should be `"_Database_Schools_dtSchools"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Method

```
Sub CreatesqldatabaseMSQL()
            Try
                Using connect As New DataSchool(Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True)
                    connect.CreateDatabase()
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub
```